# "Daily Limit Exceeded" error in python google.cloud (translate)

Tags: python, google-translate, language-detection

I want to DETECT the language of a text (and not translate) using google API.
This does not require authentications and I don't need a key.
The code is as simple as:

```
from google.cloud import translate
def detect_language(text):
    """Detects the text's language."""
    translate_client = translate.Client()
    result = translate_client.detect_language(text)

    print('Text: {}'.format(text))
    print('Confidence: {}'.format(result['confidence']))
    print('Language: {}'.format(result['language']))

print detect_language('My name is Maria')
```

However the error "google.cloud.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 Daily Limit Exceeded" pops up.
I checked my usage and made sure that I did not pass the quota ().
Also, the google translate API is enabled in console.

Any clue where does this error come from?

In another attempt, I tried this code with a key:

```
from google.cloud import translate
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

API_KEY = 'MY_KEY_COMES_HERE'

API = 'translate'

service = build(API, 'v2', developerKey=API_KEY)
print(service.translations().list(source='en', target='fr', q=['flower', 'car']).execute())

def detect_language(text):
    """Detects the text's language."""
    translate_client = translate.Client()
    result = translate_client.detect_language(text)

    print('Text: {}'.format(text))
    print('Confidence: {}'.format(result['confidence']))
    print('Language: {}'.format(result['language']))
print detect_language('My name is Maria')
```

It does translate .... but it does NOT detect the language

Comment: You sure you checked the correct project API usage?

Comment: yes, I have only 1 project.

Comment: Your code works fine with google-cloud-translate==0.22.0 on my machine, at first try.
     
On the second try, got the same error `Forbidden: 403 Daily Limit Exceeded (GET https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2/det‌​ect?q=My+name+is+Mar‌​ia`. This may be a bug in the google-api https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2/detect?q=this%20is%20maria&key=API_KEY_HERE

Answer (score 3):

What's happened is that you are not authenticated against the API so you're hitting the grace limit for anonymous API calls. API key support has diminished favoring instead service account credentials.

Create and download your service account credentials and use those for authentication as described in [the sample application](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/translate/cloud-client).